# Given the densities of 2 components in a solid mixture, could you determine the mass of one knowing the total volume and mass?

Tags: volume

Given you know the volume and mass of a solid mixture, could you determine the mass of one of the two components if you know their individual densities, I think geologist use a method that allows this, though the question might have to do with Chemistry so I'll ask on both sites.

Comment: Try constructing some linear equations based on given information. You can take two volumes as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you could. Let the total mass be $M$, total volume be $V$, densities of the two parts be $d_1$ and $d_2$. Let the unknown masses be $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Since mass is conserved, $m_1 + m_2 = M$

Since volume is also conserved, ${m_1\over d_1} + {m_2\over d_2} = V$

Linear equations in two variables, easily solvable.